# capybara: page.should have_no_content doesn't work correctly for display:none element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing, capybara

I would like to use page.should have_no_content to check if the page doesn't display the label to user, here what it is in HTML:

```
<li id="account_input" style="display: none;">
    <label for="account_name">My Account</label>
    ...
</li>
```

So when I use page.should have_no_content("My Account"), it returns false instead of true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a solution](http://makandra.com/notes/1049-check-that-a-page-element-is-not-visible-with-selenium) using:

```
Then /^"([^\"]+)" should not be visible$/ do |text|
  paths = [
    "//*[@class='hidden']/*[contains(.,'#{text}')]",
    "//*[@class='invisible']/*[contains(.,'#{text}')]",
    "//*[@style='display: none;']/*[contains(.,'#{text}')]"
  ]
  xpath = paths.join '|'
  page.should have_xpath(xpath)
end
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use this statement

```
find('#account_input').should_not be_visible
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to implement should not have

**page.should_not( have_content(arg1))**

Answer (score -1):

> So when I use page.should have_no_content("My Account"), it returns
>   false instead of true.

It should be false. Think about it this way: if your page does have the content "My account", then have_content would return True, thus have_no_content should return False. And the reason - it is not true to say that the HTML does not have the content "My account" in it. Thus, it is False.

Comment: It should return true, NOT false. It's simply a method that says: "It's true that this element does not have this content".