# Click on element with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I have a yes/no slider on a web page that i need to interact with. I need to click on one of the elements so that the value changes from true to false or false to true. Using the id i can get the value of the element with

```
find_field('passcode_policies__allow_simple').find('option[selected]').value
```

But i have tried over and over to simulate a click on this object to change the value and have been unsuccessful.

```
<div class="control-group">
  <select class="toggle" id="passcode_policies__allow_simple" name="passcode_policies[][allow_simple]" style="display: none; " tabindex="-1">
    <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
  </select>
  <div class="ui-switch off" tabindex="0">                                 
    <div class="ui-switch-mask">                          
      <div class="ui-switch-master" style="left: -38px; ">                      
        <div class="ui-switch-upper">                     
          <span class="ui-switch-handle" style="left: 33px; "></span>          
        </div>                                            
        <div class="ui-switch-lower">                     
          <div class="ui-switch-labels">                  
            <a href="#" class="ui-switch-on" style="width: 17px; " tabindex="-1">Yes</a>   
            <a href="#" class="ui-switch-off" style="width: 17px; " tabindex="-1">No</a> 
          </div>                                          
        </div>                                            
      </div>                                              
    </div>                                                
    <div class="ui-switch-middle" style="width: 60px; ">
    </div>                  
  </div>
  <label class="inline">Allow simple value</label>
  <span class="help-block">Permit the use of repeating, ascending, and descending character sequences</span>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using javascript for the toggle event - and if so - are you using selenium or a headless browser for these specs?

Comment: have you tried `click_link "Yes"` or `No`?

Comment: yes but the problem with this is that both yes and no links are visible when the css is removed. This means that if i say click yes or no it interacts with same element.

Comment: all of this is a single yes/no slider. If possible i would like to use the id to interact with this to make the rest of the tests easy

Comment: your interactive links are here though right? ` <div class="ui-switch-labels">`  
there are no ids on those anchors.

Comment: and by webdriver do you mean JSWebdriver or headless webkit or phantomjs?

Comment: webkit. and yes those dont have ids and i have tried click_link '#' because of the href. I was under the impression that I could use the class names to interact with it

Comment: from here http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method  
you can see that `click_link` finds either text, id or alt text.

Comment: `save_and_open_page` is a life saver in these situations https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/#debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium, headless webkit or phantomjs (poltergeist gem) you should be able to call the simple

```
click_link 'Yes'
```

but if you're just using straight up capybara you will have to interact with the select element with something like

```
select('Yes', :from => 'passcode_policies__allow_simple')
```

and you can check the visibility and whatnot with this [capybara: page.should have_no_content doesn't work correctly for display:none element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453729/capybara-page-should-have-no-content-doesnt-work-correctly-for-displaynone-el)

Comment: neither of those throw errors. However the first one will only interact with the first Yes link and i have not had much luck on getting the within to work to select the other yes/no options. The second solution seems to select the yes but does not click on it.

Comment: by 'the first yes link' do you mean the yes option in the select?  Otherwise, is there a second Yes link that is not shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
within(:css, '#passcode_policies__allow_simple + .ui-switch') do
  click_link 'No'
end
```

Comment: This may be the result of a code smell in your markup.  I would experiment with some markup changes before going with a result that is so difficult to read.